# JSON Data returned on NSURLConnection

Tags: arrays, json, xcode, nsurlconnection

I have an iOS app where Users have to Register before using the app. I have created the UI in Storyboard and I am reading the Users details from the UITextfields. I then send the details to the Register API that sends back a JSON response. I am using NSURLConnection for the communication.

Here is the response I am receiving from the test URL - for testing purposes only:
**{"username":"Hans","password":"Hans"}**

However, when I try to read the password to make sure that the user doesn't already exists (again, just for testing purposes), I get nil returned for password value returned.

In my .h file I declare the Data and Connection:

```
@interface RegisterViewController : UIViewController <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>
{
    // Conform to the NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol and declare an instance variable to hold the response data
    NSMutableData *buffer;
    NSURLConnection *myNSURLConnection;
}
```

In my .m file, when someone clicks the REGISTER button, I create the request and start the connection as below. I am giving a dummy URL in example but the response I am receiving is:
**{"username":"Hans","password":"Hans"}**

```
- (IBAction)registerButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myDummyURL/Login.php"]];

    // Construct the JSON Data
    NSDictionary *stringDataDictionary = @{@"firstname": firstname, @"lastname": lastname, @"email": email, @"password" : password, @"telephone" : telephone};
    NSError *error;
    NSData *requestBodyData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:stringDataDictionary options:0 error:&error];

    // Specify that it will be a POST request
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    // Set header fields
    [request setValue:@"text/plain" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [request setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    //NSData *requestBodyData = [stringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setHTTPBody:requestBodyData];

    myNSURLConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    // Ensure the connection was created
    if (myNSURLConnection)
    {
        // Initialize the buffer
        buffer = [NSMutableData data];

        // Start the request
        [myNSURLConnection start];
    }
}
```

The connection is created with no problem here.

In my .m file I implement the delegate methods and in connectionDidFinishLoading() I try and read the returned JSON. Below is the code I am using for this.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    // Dispatch off the main queue for JSON processing
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSString *jsonString = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:buffer options:0 error:&error] description];

        // Dispatch back to the main queue for UI
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            // Check for a JSON error
            if (!error)
            {
                NSError *error = nil;
                NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
                NSDictionary *dictionary = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *test = [dictionary objectForKey:@"password"];
                NSLog(@"Test is: %@", test);
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"JSON Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }

            // Stop animating the Progress HUD

        });
    });
}
```

From the log screen grab below you can see the jsonString returned has values but the jsonArray is always nil. The error reads: error   NSError *   domain: @"NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 3840  0x00007ff158498be0

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `jsonString` is in fact the `NSDictionary` object - created by `NSJSONSerialization` - you're looking for, there is no array. In a JSON string curly braces `{}` represent a dictionary and square brackets `[]` represent an array

Try this

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
  // Dispatch off the main queue for JSON processing
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:buffer options:0 error:&error];

    // Dispatch back to the main queue for UI
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        // Check for a JSON error
        if (!error)
        {
            NSString *test = [dictionary objectForKey:@"password"];
            NSLog(@"Test is: %@", test);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"JSON Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }

        // Stop animating the Progress HUD

    });
  });
}
```

**Edit:** I overlooked the `description` method at the end of the `NSJSONSerialization` line. Of course that must be deleted.

Comment: I try that and get warning when initializing the *dictionary. Warning: "incompatible pointer types initializing nsdictionary with an expression of type nsstring" And then the app crashes at line: "NSString *test = [dictionary objectForKey:@"password"];" with error: "-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Comment: Where do you log the line "JSON String …". Actually the log text is the string representation of a dictionary. Or does the received JSON string contain more than the username/password information?

Answer (score 1):

Your code has 2 issues:

1. You are converting JSON server response to NSString.
2. Your JSON data is indeed a NSDictionary.

This must fix your issue:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
  // Dispatch off the main queue for JSON processing
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:buffer options:0 error:&error];

    // Dispatch back to the main queue for UI
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        // Check for a JSON error
        if (!error)
        {
            NSString *test = [dictionary objectForKey:@"password"];
            NSLog(@"Test is: %@", test);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"JSON Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }

        // Stop animating the Progress HUD

    });
  });
}
```